# Copy dataframe in Python multiple times, and each copy have a new date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a date column. I’m trying to make it where Python copies this same information several times, 7 in this instance, and each copy has a new date value. The first date reference would be in the dataframe, then each copy after would basically have that date + 1 day.

I’m able to do the copying with Pd.concat but not able to change the date. The information is in an Excel file with a date column.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: use `dataframe.assign` to give each dataframe a new date

Comment: Not too familiar with the syntax. Can you provide an example?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html?highlight=assign#pandas.DataFrame.assign

Comment: I’m not understanding, I really appreciate your help though. The date value would be coming from an Excel file for instance. Say, if the value were in a column called Date.

Comment: Wound up doing in a roundabout way. Created a concat individually rather than one go at seven copies. In each copy I changed the date with a timedelta. One example would be:

df_repeatone = pd.concat([df_copyingfrom],ignore_index=False)

df_repeattwo = pd.concat([df_copyingfrom].ignore_index=False)
df_repeattwo['Column Name'] = df_repeattwo['Column Name'] + timedelta(days=1)

That copies the first, then in the second it copies as well but in the column I wanted to change the date it adds one. Can continue this for however many times. For me it works but bound to be a way to create more.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension in your `pandas.concat` statement:

```py
repeats = 7
fulldf = pandas.concat([
   df.assign(date=lambda df: df['date'] + timedelta(days=i)
   for i in range(repeats)
], ignore_index=True)
```